# PDF From Two Observed Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation, sampling, data-structure

I'll start with a general description and then supply my specific case. I've got data that is generated via the product of $f$ and $g$, i.e. $fg$. Both of these have distributions, and as such the product is also a distribution. I'd like to write down a probability distribution function that describes this (so I can then fit the data).

Now for the case-scenario, in a hope to clarify what I seek. My data follows $D = P \cos(\theta)$, where $P$ is a distribution of momenta and $\theta$ is a distribution of angles such that $\cos(\theta)$ is a uniform distribution. This can be seen here: [[image: Distribution of <span class=]$\cos(\theta)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cms6Q.png)

The distribution of momenta appears to be exponential in simplest approximation, but maybe more-so like a beta distribution. It looks like this:[[image: Distribution of <span class=]$P$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9icCx.png)

The actual data is generate by the product of these sets, and when binned looks like the following:[[image: Distribution of the data, <span class=]$D = P \cos(\theta)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPO46.png)

To summarize, I can write an approximate PDF for $P$ in the domain of energy, and would like to do the same for $D$, but don't know how to mix in the angular component. If a convolution is necessary, I don't see how to perform it because the PDF I'd write for the angular component wouldn't be in the same domain (Energy) as the momenta $P$.

To try and frame my question with the correct terminology, given a PDF of $f(x)$ and random variable $U$, how can I write the composite PDF $h(x)=f(x)\,U$?

Comment: [Product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Thanks @AaronHendrickson. This looks similar to convolution attempts I made earlier. I'll try defining $f_x$ and $f_y$ and applying it per the page/link. The only thing I'm fearful of at this moment is that the angular distribution doesn't have a definition in terms of energy, like the momenta do.

Comment: So you have a random variable of the form $D=PU$, where $U\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(-1,1)$. I'm assuming that $P$ and $U$ are independent?To define an analytical expression for the density of $D$ you need a model for the exact density of $P$. Once you have that simply apply the formula for the density of a product.